# Custom cell actions based on object attribute in TableRow in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

everybody.

I have a javaFx tableView like this :

```
-----------------------------------------
| Name       |  Date       | actions    |
-----------------------------------------
| jack       |23-06-2016   | B1  B2  B3 |
-----------------------------------------
| Jane       |12-02-2017   | B1  B2  B3 |
-----------------------------------------
| Mickel     |22-05-2017   | B1  B2  B3 |
-----------------------------------------
```

The actions column is rendered using a *CustomCellTable*. It contains three buttons (B1, B2, and B3 )

I want the B3 button to be enabled only if the corresponding date is the maximum in the table.

In the example above, the B3 button of the last row should be enabled , the others shouldn't

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are the dates for each row fixed, or can they change during the time the table is displayed?

Comment: The rows are backed by JavaFx Beans having SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> for the date attribute, which can be changed at runtime . (the B3 button dislays a dialog to edit the bean, and thus the row )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a model class that looks like

```
public class Person {

    // ...

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

    public ObjetProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
        return date ;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return dateProperty().get();
    }

    // ...
}
```

and if you create the items list for the table with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-):

```
ObservableList<Person> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(p -> new Observable[] {p.dateProperty()});
tableData.addAll(...);
table.setItems(tableData);
```

then you can do

```
ObjectBinding<Person> personWithLatestDate = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
        tableData.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getDate)).orElse(null), 
        tableData);
```

and your actions column can look like:

```
TableColumn<Person, Person> actionsColumn = new TableColumn<>("Actions");
actionsColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue()));

actionsColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Person, Person>() {
    // ...
    Button b3 = new Button(...) ;
    HBox buttons = new HBox(5, b1, b2, b3);
    // ...

    {
         b3.disableProperty().bind(itemProperty().isNotEqualTo(personWithLatestDate));
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(person, empty);
        setGraphic(empty ? null : buttons);
    }
});
```

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Comparator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class TableCelDisableButton extends Application {

    private ObservableList<Person> tableData;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(p -> new Observable[] {p.dateProperty()});
        table.setItems(tableData);

        ObjectBinding<Person> personWithLatestDate = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
                tableData.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getDate)).orElse(null), 
                tableData);

        TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, LocalDate> dateCol = new TableColumn<>("Date");
        dateCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dateProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, Person> actionsCol = new TableColumn<>("Actions");
        actionsCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue()));

        actionsCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Person, Person>() {
            Button edit = new Button("Edit");
            Button button = new Button("Click");
            HBox buttons = new HBox(5, edit, button);

            {
                edit.setOnAction(e -> edit(getItem(), primaryStage, false));
                button.disableProperty().bind(itemProperty().isNotEqualTo(personWithLatestDate));
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(person, empty);
                setGraphic(empty ? null : buttons);
            }
        });

        table.getColumns().add(nameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(dateCol);
        table.getColumns().add(actionsCol);

        table.getItems().add(new Person("Jack", LocalDate.of(2016, 6, 23)));
        table.getItems().add(new Person("Jane", LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 12)));
        table.getItems().add(new Person("Mikel", LocalDate.of(2017, 5, 22)));

        Button add = new Button("Add");
        add.setOnAction(e -> edit(new Person("", LocalDate.now()), primaryStage, true));

        Button delete = new Button("Delete");
        delete.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
        delete.setOnAction(e -> tableData.remove(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()));

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, add, delete);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table, null, null, buttons, null), 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void edit(Person person, Window primaryStage, boolean addOnCommit) {
        GridPane editor = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
        leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
        rightCol.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
        editor.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);

        editor.setHgap(5);
        editor.setVgap(8);
        editor.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        editor.add(new Label("Name:"), 0, 0);
        editor.add(new Label("Date"), 0, 1);
        TextField name = new TextField(person.getName());
        editor.add(name, 1, 0);
        DatePicker date = new DatePicker(person.getDate());
        editor.add(date, 1, 1);

        Button ok = new Button("OK");
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, ok, cancel);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        editor.add(buttons, 0, 2, 2, 1);


        Scene scene = new Scene(editor);
        Stage editDialog = new Stage();
        editDialog.setScene(scene);
        editDialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        editDialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
        editDialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        editDialog.sizeToScene();

        ok.setOnAction(e -> {
            person.setName(name.getText());
            person.setDate(date.getValue());
            if (addOnCommit) {
                tableData.add(person);
            }
            editDialog.hide();
        });

        cancel.setOnAction(e -> editDialog.hide());

        editDialog.show();
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public Person(String name, LocalDate date) {
            setName(name);
            setDate(date);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
            return this.date;
        }


        public final java.time.LocalDate getDate() {
            return this.dateProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setDate(final java.time.LocalDate date) {
            this.dateProperty().set(date);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with the ObjectBinding<localDate> it says `The method createObjectBinding(Callable<T>, Observable...) in the type Bindings is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {}, ObservableList<Person>)` and `The method max(Comparator<? super Person>) in the type Stream<Person> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>>)`

Comment: corrected it as you said, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried debugging, and figured that the Person person argument of the `updateItem` method is always null. And also when i inspect the latestDate binding i see some "invalide" text.

Comment: The SSCCE works (try it), so you just have something set up differently (or maybe you skipped the `setCellValueFactory(...)` line).

Comment: Edited with a slightly simpler approach. (It worked fine the other way, this is just a bit more straightforward.)

Comment: This line of code was missing `actionsColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue()));` now it works perfectly, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: That line was [always there](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38680261/revisions). Glad it works for you.